# why does numpy.trapz behave differently with booleans than with ints?

Tags: python, numpy

Booleans in Python are implemented as ints and usually there is no difference in `numpy` and other packages when changing `0` by `False` and `1` by `True`.
Why then these two computations differ?

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.trapz([1,1])
1.0
>>> np.trapz([True, True])
0.5
```

The same thing happens with `scipy.integrate`.

Comment: `np.trapz(np.array([1,1]).astype(object))` gives 1.

Answer (score 3):

Found it. It seems to be a bug:
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12858

As pointed in the issue, the key is that

```py
>>> True + True
2
>>> np.True_ + np.True_
True
```